What wil be the IUPAC name of the following compound?
What will be the IUPAC name of the following compound?
Like I am confused between 2 names
2-(cyclopent1,4dienyl)propan-2-ol and
1-(cyclopent-1 4-dienyl)1-methyl ethan-1-ol
The second one seems more correct. Please someone verify 

A IUPAC name is not a synonym for a systematic IUPAC name, as not all of them are systematic. E.g. the preferred IUPAC name is acetic acid, while the systematic IUPAC name is ethanoic acid.

The systematic IUPAC name of isopropylalcohol is propan-2-ol and not 1-methyl-ethan-1-ol.

Your main chain can consist of a maximum of 2 carbons, and we shall give locant preference to the alcohol group, so the correct name is the second one
1-(cyclopent-1, 4-dienyl)-1-methyl ethan-1-ol
For further verification, you can plug in this name at https://web.chemdoodle.com/demos/iupac-naming#written_tab
Note that the entire closed chain is to be treated as a substituent, and when compared to a substituent, —OH is definitely preferred. And once we define the group, we can have a maximum of 2 carbon in a single chain with the alcohol.
Though, the first name will work too, the former one is more elaborate.
Why not cyclopent-(1, 3-diene) as the main chain?
Two reasons, primary one that if that is the main chain, you shall have a hydroxy substituent instead of a functional group. Secondly, making ethane as the main chain, we have 2 substituents (methyl and cyclopent-1,4 dienyl) compared to a single substituent on the closed chain.
